# Issue with IndexOutofBounds and list.remove Java

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

FIXED IT WAS A DUMB ERROR THAT HAD NOTHING TO DO WITH THE QUESTION

Im writing code to play a game
I've created an array list called cards filled with 81 numbers
I run this code in a loop (along with some other stuff) 9 times at the beginning to initialize and it works fine, but when I go to run it again after the first round of playing it gives me an index out of bounds exception
I have debugged it and in the last instance the cards.size was 68 and the choice was 58 so logically it should work

```
choice=(int) (Math.random()*cards.size());
card= (int)cards.get(choice);
cards.remove(choice)
```

Oh and if you are playing it, the way you get a set and pull up the error is by having three items where every number is the same for all three or different for all three
example:
0:3212
5:1231
7:2223
in the first column there is a 1 2 and a 3, in the second column they are all 2s and so on

FULL LONG CODE

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math.*; 
// This tries to play a version of the game of set with no GUI(because I havent learned it yet)
//It is supposed to crash eventually if you use all the cards or go to a stalemate if there are no cards on the board
// but it is crashing sooner than it should
public class Setdeath {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Initializing all of the stuff so i don't have to later
      int fir, sec, thi, dog, k, klat, qa, qb, firsti, secondi, narc, choice, card, carda, x, tricar, ex, first, second, third;
      int trid;
      double v, bees;
      // Where I create the list it's just numbers 0-80
      List cards= new ArrayList();
      k=0;
      while (k<81){
         cards.add(k);
         k++;
      }
   // put 12 cards in a list
      List table= new ArrayList();
      k=1;
      while (k<13){
         choice=(int) (Math.random()*cards.size());
         card= (int)cards.get(choice);
         cards.remove(choice);
         carda=card;
   // this converts it into a trinary ish thing for gameplay
         ex=(carda/27);
         carda= carda- ex*27;
         tricar= 1000*(ex+1);
         ex=(carda/9);
         carda= carda- ex*9;
         tricar= 100*(ex+1)+tricar;
      
         ex=(carda/3);
         carda= carda- ex*3;
         tricar= 10*(ex+1)+tricar;
      
         ex=(carda);
         tricar=ex+1+tricar;
      
         table.add(tricar);
         k++;
      }
   
   // for repeat
      for(;;){
         k=0;
         while (k<12){
            dog=(int)table.get(k);
            System.out.println(k+": "+dog);
            k++;}
      
      // get three cards spots
         System.out.print("What's Piece A? ");
         fir = keyboard.nextInt();
         System.out.print("What's Piece B? ");
         sec = keyboard.nextInt();
         System.out.print("What's Piece C? ");
         thi = keyboard.nextInt();
      // initialize cards
         first= (int)table.get(fir);
         second= (int)table.get(sec);
         trid= (int)table.get(thi);
      
      
         v=3.0;
         third=0;
         firsti=first;
         secondi=second;
         // this takes the first two cards and finds the third card to make a match
         while (v>-1){
            bees = Math.pow(10.0,v);
            narc =(int)bees;
            qa= firsti/(narc);
            qb= secondi/(narc);
            firsti=firsti-qa*narc;
            secondi=secondi-qb*narc;
            if (qa==qb){
               third= third+ qa*narc;}
            else {
               third= third+ (6-qa-qb)*narc;}
            v--;
         }
         // If a match is made than we remove the 3 cards from the table and add three more
      
         if (trid==third){
            System.out.println("Set");
            table.remove(thi);
            table.remove(sec);
            table.remove(fir);
            klat=0;
            //where it crashes
            while (klat<3){
               choice=(int) (Math.random()*cards.size());
               card= (int)cards.get(choice);
               cards.remove(choice);
            
            //Converts to trinary to put back on the table
               carda=card;
               ex=(carda/27);
               carda= carda- ex*27;
               tricar= 1000*(ex+1);
               ex=(carda/9);
               carda= carda- ex*9;
               tricar= 100*(ex+1)+tricar;
            
               ex=(carda/3);
               carda= carda- ex*3;
               tricar= 10*(ex+1)+tricar;
            
               ex=(carda);
               tricar=ex+1+tricar;
               // adds it to the table
            
               table.add(tricar);
               k++;
            }}
         else{
            System.out.print("Not a set");}
      }}}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code method that generate the Exception?

Comment: It is long and very gross is there a specific thing you are looking for? I don't want to post the whole code because stylistically I am a terrible coder and I have a lot of work to do on that

Comment: The only other place I use cards in the code is to initialize the list and populate it with the numbers.  The only other place I use choice is to initialize it as an integer.

Comment: I will post the whole code or other sections of it if needed though, I just don't know how readable it will be

Comment: don't worry about that... the idea in this community is help and maybe you get one or two tips about your code ;)

Comment: Ok give me a second to annotate

Comment: I added the full code to the bottom of the post, sorry about the weird variable names and the extreme inefficiencies

Comment: Sorry about this i am just learning

Comment: Rather than posting "FULL LONG CODE" please reduce this to a [mcve]. Also note that Java is not Javascript, so please don't click the "Javascript snippet" button. (Reducing it to a minimal example may well take you a while, but it'll be worth it - you may very well find the problem while doing so.)

Comment: I fixed it, It was a while loop where n was less than 5 and I had a k++ at the end instead of an n++  thanks for everyones help, I think this question might have to be deleted or something because the problem that I had was not the question that was asked, I am new to stack overflow as an asker so if someone could help me close it up that would be helpful

Comment: Consider removing the question

Comment: how would i do that?